# Stage of the rendering pipeline

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a question and must finish it in 2 days:

> Considering the stages of the rendering pipeline, if you have a low
>   FPS, what stage will come first in your mind as being more probable to
>   be the origin of your problem?

Anyone could help me understand, or give me a clue,

Thanks,

Comment: What does this have to do with any form of OpenGL? This question is also *highly* speculative; there's no reasonable answer without more information about what is being rendered. The correct answer is to *benchmark* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

things to consider:

- **Draw Calls**: do you use glBegin/glEnd, call glVertex several thousand times? Or maybe you are using too many glDrawArrays? maybe you send too many data each frame from sys memory to the GPU?
- **Vertex shader**: do you have simple vertex shader or complex, change it to simple one and check fps... is is better or still it is to low?
- **Fragment shader**: number of texture reads, if statements, instruction complexity. Change resolution of the window and check the fps.
- **Buffer usage**: do you use buffers on the GPU, or maybe transfer everything from mem to gpu mem? try using 1x1 textures to check the performance.
- **Tools**: use tools to perform measurments: geDebugger, glIntercept, etc...

there are other things like (and probably I forgot to list even more): geometry shaders, tesselation, but first check the above list.

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/opengl-optimization-tips
- [gpu gems, Chapter 28. Graphics Pipeline Performance](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch28.html)

in general: measure, measure, measure :)